# MobX - Reset all store observables back to initial state?

Tags: javascript, mobx

Given a `MyQuestionStore` store:

```
class MyQuestionStore {
  @observable asked = 'today';
  @observable answered = false;
  @observable question = {
    upvotes: 0,
    body: null,
    asker: null,
    askerPoints: null,
    askerBadges: null
  }
  // some more initial state observables...
  // some actions below...
}

const myQuestionStore = new MyQuestionStore();
export default myQuestionStore;
```

What would be the correct way to reset all store observables back to their initial states data ('today'/false/0/null/etc..)?

**NOTE:** Something like `MyQuestionStore.reset()` for example I think would be a good MobX way, but I don't think it exists. I would have to write an action called `reset` and manually reset each observable back to its initial state. I don't think that would be the right way, since if I add more `observables`, I would have to manually add them to the `reset` action every time.

Comment: MobX does not track the previous values, so a manual reset you are talking about is not a bad idea.

Comment: I see.. I think even if MobX doesn't track them that's okay. I was thinking maybe a method can "snapshot" the initial state of the observables, and pull it back out on hitting the `reset()` I am just trying to figure out a way without having to manually maintain observables reset one by one (in case I forget to add an observable in the reset).

Comment: Can't you just create a new store based on the same class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*EDIT*: this is an old answer that doesn’t work in newer versions of mobx.

If you use the `reset()` to initialize the object, you could avoid duplication of code. Here is what I mean:

```
import { extendObservable } from "mobx";

class MyQuestionStore {
  constructor() {
    this.reset();
  }

  @action reset() {
    extendObservable(this, {
      asked: 'today',
      answered: false,
      question: {
        upvotes: 0,
        body: null,
        asker: null,
        askerPoints: null,
        askerBadges: null
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Works very well, thank you! One minor edit is semicolons should be commas (SO won't allow me to just change them on an answer unless I change 6 characters, which I don't need to do) :)

Comment: `extendObservable()` doesn't reset existing observables, so it sounds like running `reset()` outside of the constructor wouldn't actually have the desired effect. So, in short, this doesn't work.

Comment: @Dygerati I'm quite confident this snippet was working in older versions of mobx. I'm not up-to-date with the latest changes in mobx, would you mind adding a snippet that would work for the recent versions of mobx?

Comment: @MouadDebbar Understood, that makes sense. I'm actually not aware of a working method to do this so far, but I'll report back if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 5):

To reset store you can do something like this:

```
const initialValue = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 19,
}

@action reset() {
  Object.keys(initialState).forEach(key => this[key] = initialState[key]);
}
```

And you can set initial store values:

```
class myStore {
  constructor() {
    extendObservable(this, initialState);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended up having to repeat the default observables in the reset function, so it looks like this:

```
class MyQuestionStore {
  @observable asked = 'today';
  @observable answered = false;
  @observable question = {
    upvotes: 0,
    body: null,
    asker: null,
    askerPoints: null,
    askerBadges: null
  }

  @action reset = () => {
    this.asked = 'today';
    this.answered = false;
    this.question = {
      upvotes: 0,
      body: null,
      asker: null,
      askerPoints: null,
      askerBadges: null
    }
  }
}

const myQuestionStore = new MyQuestionStore();
export default myQuestionStore;
```

I still feel there is a better way than to repeat it and keep it DRY. I will keep the question open for now, hoping there is a better DRY answer.

Comment: I heard that combination of mobx's `toJS` and lodash `deepMerge` worked well for others

Comment: hmmm.. didn't know that as I've never used `deepMerge` from lodash. Thanks for sharing and for the awesome mobx!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to reset deeply, the `createViewModel` utility from `mobx-utils` might come in handy: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils/#createviewmodel

Comment: Hmmm... Yeah I think I am trying to reset deeply regardless of the number of times the observable was changed, sort of back to the base line default.

Answer (score 1):

Why not going with the following approach

```
class MyQuestionStore {
   @observable asked;
   @observable answered;
   @observable question;

   constructor() {
      super()
      this.init()
   }

   @action reset() {
      this.init()
   }

   @action init() {
     this.asked = 'today';
     this.answered = false;
     this.question = {
         upvotes: 0,
         body: null,
         asker: null,
         askerPoints: null,
         askerBadges: null
      }
   }

  // some more initial state observables...
  // some actions below...
}

const myQuestionStore = new MyQuestionStore();
export default myQuestionStore;
```